# application starts from beginning after kindle autolocks

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I have an application that i have to run in kindle fire.

The application is running fine,but after kindle autolocks,application starts from beginning and not from where the application was before the autolock.

why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are saving your application's state.

Activities in Android have a very special lifecycle. Whenever an app is put in the background, it calles `onPause()` and when you bring it back into view, `onResume()` is called.

So you'll want to save the state whenever `onPause()` or `onStop()` is called and load the state on `onCreate()` and `onResume()`

For more about states, read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Edit:
Also have a look at [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: thanks but can u plz provide some code to save the last instance state?actually i have a grid view in a fragment.images are downloaded into the gridview through sm links.at this point if i autolock the screen...am getting a NullPointer Exception at InitGridView() method.

Comment: Finally got a code that holds the last state of the fragment     @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
android:configChanges=["mcc", "mnc", "locale",
                             "touchscreen", "keyboard", "keyboardHidden",
                             "navigation", "screenLayout", "fontScale", "uiMode",
                             "orientation", "screenSize", "smallestScreenSize"]
```

in the manifest and create an override function for onConfigChange in activity.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a code that holds the last state of the fragment  after kindle/galaxy tab autolocks.                           @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }